# Calculating heat transfer in a cooling loop

Tags: thermodynamics, heat-transfer, cooling, convection

Imagine a closed pipe like below, filled with a liquid. The pipe is copper.  Then imagine a small point heat source of X watts applied to the outside of the pipe in the position shown.  Heat warms the pipe, then the liquid, and circulation develops.  As there's only heat applied on one side of the loop, the liquid naturally cools in the other half.  There'll be convection and radiation there.

[image: water loop]

Is there any way I could begin to model this so that I could establish a temperature rise at the heat source?  So for example, X watts input would lead to a Y degree temperature rise in the pipe at the point of application.

For context, I'm looking at a heat source of say 10W, and a maximum rise of 20 degrees.  So the design element here is the size of the loop and the diameter of the pipe.  I would like to nominally target ⌀22mm for the pipe.

I don't have access to finite elements. A back of the envelope, on a toilet wall or a fag packet calculation would be appreciated.  Is it even possible or does this have to be determined empirically?

Comment: So I understand, you envision the liquid keeping the area of the pipe exposed to the heating element below a temperature rise of 20 deg. Celsius?

Comment: @J.Ari Yes, that's correct.

Comment: You could simplify this problem into a 1D conduction type problem (Fourier equation) but I don't know that the simplification would be valid because I doubt the degree of cooling you say will be present at the opposite side of the loop. Are you providing forced convection with a fan or something?

Comment: @J.Ari Nope.  It's entirely passive (so silent). Clearly the concept works on  a ludicrous scale.  If the pipe was ⌀1000mm and the overall size was 10m then there'd be no discernible temp. rise.  What about something smaller..?

Comment: So I think you can still simply to the 1D conduction type problem and work out pipe temp for a period of time, use those results to do a conduction heat transfer calc for the water being heated by the pipe, and then figure out how much convection could develop (long story short, do an energy balance). My intuition is to say not much natural convection will develop and that the mostly stagnant water loop won't be able to give you the amount of cooling you need.

Comment: @J.Ari Why do you call it stagnant?  Do you think that convection won't start?  Are there limitations on convection?

Comment: Rayleigh number (Ra) can tell you if your system will have natural convection or not. For the particular case in your question, I don't think there will be appreciable convection developed because the pipe is only going to be 22mm OD (Ra is proportional to the cube of the diameter) and heat input is not so high as to generate a large temperature difference quickly (Ra is directly proportional to density differences within the medium).

Comment: I think the most valid simplification is to consider for initial calculation is heat transfer from the outer wall of the pipe to inner wall of the pipe (conduction) and then heat transfer from inner wall of pipe to the water (conduction) within the length of pipe directly exposed to the heat source.

Comment: From my previous comment "the pipe is only going to be 22mm OD (Ra is proportional to the cube of the diameter)". This is assuming the loop is positioned horizontally . If the loop were positioned vertically, then Ra would be proportional to the cube of the pipe length. By the definition of Ra, you use the characteristic length of the convection.